# Is there a way to remove all repeated keys except the last one in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array of messages received from server, with key **seen_by** which contain users saw the message, it's structure :

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [seen_by] => Array
            (
                [1] => user_1
                [2] => user_2
                [3] => user_3
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [seen_by] => Array
            (
                [2] => user_2
                [3] => user_3
            )

    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [seen_by] => Array
            (
                [3] => user_3
            )

    )
```

where they keys in **seen_by** array is user_id,

what i want to do is since user_2 already in the **seen_by** array of the second message ,so remove it from the first **seen_by** array , and since user_3 in **seen_by** array of third message , remove from the first two messages

I want to get array like

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [seen_by] => Array
            (
                [1] => user_1
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [seen_by] => Array
            (
                [2] => user_2
            )

    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [seen_by] => Array
            (
                [3] => user_3
            )

    )
```

Comment: If user_2 saw messages 1 and 2, why would you want to remove user_2 from message 1?  Wouldn't that mean that user_2 did not see message 1 and only saw message 2?  If these arrays actually represent the same message then why not merge the users into a single array?

Comment: @DaveS nope , I want to do something like messenger actually , so when user icon under message it mean he saw all the previous , each of those arrays represent message , and have other keys like time of message , the name of sender, etc but i trimmed them to focus in seen_by key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreach loop and loop from last to first. To do so, use `array_reverse()`. Use a `$set` to check *if a  user is already tracked* using `isset`. If it is, `unset` it from the current subarray or add it to the `$set` and move with the next element. An `array_reverse` at the end is done again just to restore the original order.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function removeDups($data){
    $set = [];
    $res = [];
    foreach(array_reverse($data) as &$sub){
        foreach($sub['seen_by'] as $idx => $val){
            if(isset($set[ $val ])){
                unset($sub['seen_by'][ $idx ]);
            }else{
                $set[ $val ] = true; 
            }
        }
        $res[] = $sub;
    }
    return array_reverse($res);
}

print_r(removeDups($data));
```

[**Online Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c97325aadbd86c94503f3d93dde16cbba16ae82)

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified the arrays for illustration but the idea is shown.  You can loop through the arrays starting at the end and working backwards, removing elements that exist in later arrays.

```
$array = array(
    array( 1, 2, 3 ),
    array( 2, 3 ),
    array( 3 ),
);
$len = count( $array );
for ( $i = $len -1 ; $i > 0; $i-- ) {
    $curr_array = $array[ $i ];
    for( $j = $i - 1; $j >= 0; $j-- ) {
        $array[$j] = array_diff( $array[$j], $curr_array );
    }
}
```